# Polynomial Evaluation. How to (formally) substitute X with a Matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-rings

for simplicity a specific case:

$f:=(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}[X]$

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$

In one of our assignments f is evaluated as $\sum_{i=0}^{\deg(f)} a_iA^i$.

How is this evaluation possible formally since $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subring of $\mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$? Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Polynomial_evaluation

greets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, what matters is that the operations make sense after substitution.
If you take some structure that is not a ring, say the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, and you try to compute $f(a)$ for $a$ in $\mathbb{N}$, you probably won't find an integer.
This is why, in the article, the element $a$ has to be part of a ring.

Now, why does $R$ have to contain $K$? This is to allow the multiplication by the $a_i$ coefficients of the polynomial.

Take the ring $M_4(\mathbb{Z})$, matrices with integers coefficients, and $M$ a matrix in that set. Then, what is $\pi M$? It is not part of our ring $M_4(\mathbb{Z})$.

In our case, you can multiply a matrix that has real coefficients by a real number, and get back a matrix with real coefficients (some call this an [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra)).
You can also add two real matrices together, and get back a real matrix. Thus, all the operations make sense.

Another way to answer your question would be to say that $$\tilde K = \{\lambda I_4,  \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}, +, .) = K$. Indeed, the function $$\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \lambda I_4 \in \tilde K$$
is a ring isomorphism, mapping $K$ to $\tilde K$. So, in a way, $M_4(\mathbb{R})$ contains $\mathbb{R}$.

Another interesting property to think about is commutativity. Indeed, matrices do not commute in general. However, if you stick to one matrix, and transformations such as $(+, .)$ applied iteratively to the $a_iA^k$, this works just fine.

Comment: hey, thx a lot for your quick and detailed response. You are right with your isomorphism idea. I found a more general definition of polynomial evaluation which answers my question. (though it's in german unfortunately) The idea is to use homomorphisms if it doesnt "formally fit" in the first place. greets :)